# typescript from callback back to function

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I'm using mongodb driver to connect mongo:

```
 public listUsers(filterSurname?:string):any {

        if (this.connected) {
            debug.log(this.db);
            var results;
            this.db.collection('userProfiles').find({}).toArray((err:Error, res:any[])=> {
                if (err) return 'getting results error'
                else {
                    results=res;
                    results = res;
                }
                return res;
            });
        }
        debug.log('sending results' + results);
        if (results !== null) {

            return results;
        }
        else return 'connection error';
        return 'db unknown error'

    }
```

function to array has next signature:

```
toArray(callback: (err: Error, results: any[]) => any) : void;
```

I can't change singnature, how can I return value back to function from callback?
Is there any way except one more callback? Or typescript providing same callback hell solution?

Comment: If you can't do something in JS, you can't do the same thing in TS. Maybe you should encapsulate `toArray` in a promise.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is to return out a synchronous result from an asynchronous process (database query).

You will need to implement a strategy for handling asynchronous results, here are a few options:

> Pass in a callback function into listUsers

```
public listUsers(filterSurname?:string, 
  callback: (err: Error, results: any[])=>void):any {
  if (this.connected) {
        debug.log(this.db);
        var results;
        this.db.collection('userProfiles').find({}).toArray(callback);
    }
    debug.log('sending results' + results);
    if (results !== null) {

        return results;
    }
    else return 'connection error';
    return 'db unknown error'

}
```

> Return a promise

There are few promise libraries out there, the most popular being `Q` and `bluebird`

Here is an example using `Q`

```
 public listUsers(filterSurname?:string): Q.Promise<any[]> {
   var defer = Q.defer(); // create the promise structure
   if (this.connected) {
     debug.log(this.db);
     this.db.collection('userProfiles')
       .find({})
       .toArray((err:Error, res:any[])=> {
         if (err) {
           // reject the promise
           //     means something went wrong
           defer.reject('getting results error');
         } else {
           // resolve the promise
           //     means here is the result of what
           //     I promised I would give you
           defer.resolve(res);
         }
       });
   }
   return defer.promise; // return out the actual promise
 }
```